# Insert List<T> in table

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, web-services

I am not the best with oracle sql.

I have `List<T>` on webservice and I need send list to client side of application.

After that I need write distinct list data in table, and join with few other tables.

For example:

I have define:

```
public class VIEW_COLOR
{
    public int COL_NAME_CODE { get; set; }
    public int COL_DESC_CODE { get; set; }
}
```

I get data with

```
public List<VIEW_COLOR> GetColor()
{
    string sql = "select distinct * from VIEW_COLOR";
    IEnumerable<VIEW_COLOR"> loc = _connection.Query<VIEW_COLOR>(sql);
    return loc.ToList<VIEW_COLOR"=>();            
}
```

Than i use:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<VIEW_COLOR> GetColor()
{
    return dal.GetLColor();
}
```

I try this part and I get that in list on webservice list.

I have tables:

> Table  desc_name have code, tab_col_d_name
>   Table  name_desc have code, tab_col_n_desc

Now i need that application when I input this data to client side , and insert in full_table that have columns:

```
 1. tab_col_name_code 

 2. tab_col_name_desc

 3. tab_col_desc_code      

 4. tab_col_desc_name
```

Table desc_name have

```
 1. tab_col_d_name 
 2. tab_col_d_code
```

Table name_desc have

```
 1. tab_col_n_desc  
 2. tab_col_n_code
```

I need to insert in local `full_table tab_col_name_code=COL_NAME_CODE` and `tab_col_name_desc= tab_col_n_name` where `tab_col_n_code = COLOR_DESC_CODE` (from list) and for second two columns same.

I hope I was clearly with this, I am not best with English and was little hard explain what I try to do.

Comment: What particular problem do you have?

Comment: I dont know how send list from webserver to client side of apps, and how write sql witch wold insert in table "where field = value from list"

Comment: If it is a list then you can send it as JSON string which will be easy to handle on the client. Once the user has selected the required values you can send them back to the webservice and use parameterized query to insert or update values in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q**: "I dont know how send list from webserver to client side of apps"

**A**: Call your server webmethod on client side and get the result.

**Q**: "how write sql witch wold insert in table "where field = value from list"

**A**: You may create SQL query dynamically or use some ORM layer to insert data through ORM-generated entities.